# Shortest Distance Between Two Lines

Tags: calculus

Find the shortest distance between two lines: $$x=\frac{y}{2}=-z$$ $$x-1=y=z$$

I have done similar problems with vectors passing through points but I have no idea how to approach this one. It doesn't seem like it will work with $$d=\begin{vmatrix}\frac{(V_1 \times V_2)\bullet P_1P_2}{V_1 \times V_2}\end{vmatrix}$$ Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @Bye_World If I could have found it on SE or Wikipedia, I wouldn't have posted it on here.

Answer (score 1):

The lines have direction vectors $\vec{a}=\langle1,2,-1\rangle$ and $\vec{b}=\langle1,1,1\rangle$, so let $\vec{n}=\vec{a}\times\vec{b}=\langle3,-2,-1\rangle$.

This gives a normal vector to the planes $3x-2y-z=0$ and $3x-2y-z=3$ which contain each of the lines, and the distance between the lines is equal to the distance between these planes.

This is given by the distance from (0,0,0) to the plane $3x-2y-z=3$,

which is equal to  $\displaystyle d=\frac{|3(0)-2(0)-0-3|}{\sqrt{3^2+2^2+1^2}}=\frac{3}{\sqrt{14}}$.

---

Alternate method:

Using the parametric equations $x=s, y=2s, z=-s$ and $x=1+t, y=t, z=t$,

let $f(s,t)=d^2=(1+t-s)^2+(t-2s)^2+(t+s)^2$.

Then $f_s=0\implies3t-2s=-1$, and $f_t=0\implies 2t-6s=-1$.

Solving gives $s=\frac{1}{14}$ and $t=-\frac{2}{7}$, so the minimum distance is given by

$\displaystyle\hspace{.3 in}d=\sqrt{f\left(\frac{1}{14},-\frac{2}{7}\right)}=\frac{3\sqrt{14}}{14}$

Answer (score 0):

Pick a point $P$ (arbitrary) on line 1 and a point $Q$ (arbitrary) on the second line. Create the vector $\vec{QP}$, then your answer should be
\begin{align}
\text{distance}= \frac{|| \vec{PQ}\times \vec{d}_2||}{||\vec{d}_2||}
\end{align} 
where $\vec{d}_2$ is the direction of line 2.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would find "the direction of line 2" since I don't have a vector to begin with.

Comment: Sure you do. It's $(t+1, t, t) = t(1, 1, 1)+(1, 0, 0)$ which gives you the initial point and the direction.

Comment: @martycohen do you mean $(t-1,t,t)$ ?

Comment: On the second equation if $y=z=t$ then $x=t+1$.

Comment: When I use this, I end up getting 0 for the distance, which I don't think is right...

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out! Was forgetting to square when finding magnitudes. Thanks!